Using Playwright for end to end tests of embedded flutter application
So currently I have been developing a flutter application that is now embedded in to a react web application. When we get to a certain point in the application we switch and load a flutter app flutter for a specific flow.
We currently use playwright as a testing suite for out applications and it works very well except for the new flutter portion. I am having issue piercing the canvas. Has anyone had any luck using :
SemanticsBinding.instance.ensureSemantics();
Specifically looking at web applications. Flutter in our mobile application seems to work without issue using Appium with some tweaks and using the semantics widgets wrapping custom widgets. The web implementation is the issue.
Are they any resources for using Semantics for end to end tests in place of the usual element selectors.
In a standalone version it seems to work. I see the sematic tree and node populate. Simply by using the semantics biding but playwright codegen sees some nodes and gives me the first set of selectors but when I hit continue I can interreact with the page but it is not recording that I am selecting anything which is a regression to the original problem of not seeing node. But in the element inspector I can see unique nodes.

There is no official support for Flutter in Playwright, nor are they prioritizing adding it anytime soon.
See this thread for more information (and potential future updates, as this might change):
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26587#issuecomment-1693876574
